# How do I add double-quotes to each item in my input string?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to concatenate a string into an object, with the format of `"test@yahoo.com,abc@gmail.com,123@yahoo.com"`. However, the parameter is expecting every value in the string to be surrounded by quotes, such as `""test@yahoo.com","abc@gmail.com","123@yahoo.com""`. The error is "Property validation failed", and it is expecting a System.String. How do I go about resolving this?

The exact lines of code are...

```
$existingconfig = get-mailboxjunkemailconfiguration $_.address
$existingconfig.trustedsendersanddomains += $_.approved_senders
```

where `$_.approved_senders = "test@yahoo.com,abc@gmail.com,123@yahoo.com"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Identity BSmith | Get-Memeber` shows that the TrustedSendersAndDomains property is a multiValuedProperty string, i.e. an Array.  You can try changing the value of the `$_.approved_senders` into an array with `-Split`

```
$existingconfig = get-mailboxjunkemailconfiguration $_.address
$existingconfig.trustedsendersanddomains += ($_.approved_senders -Split ",")
```